# sleep function in C11

Tags: c, sleep, c11

I want to sleep in a C11 program. Neither usleep (in unistd.h) nor nanosleep (in time.h) are declared with the `-std=c11` option of both gcc (4.8.2) and clang (3.2).

A `grep sleep /usr/include/*.h` doesn't reveal any other likely sleep candidates.

I need a sleep with at least millisecond precision.

How do I sleep in C11?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c11` (this works for both clang and gcc). This will cause the `<time.h>` header to define `nanosleep`.

Another alternative to `nanosleep`, calling `pselect` on a null file descriptor with a timeout, also only works with `-std=gnu11` and not `-std=c11`

For an example of both:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main()  // Compile with -std=gnu11 (and not -std=c11)
{
   struct timespec ts1 = {
       .tv_sec = 0,
       .tv_nsec = 500*1000*1000
   };
   printf("first\n");
   nanosleep(&ts1, NULL);
   printf("second\n");
   pselect(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ts1, NULL);
   printf("third\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the threads.h header there is the thrd_sleep function

```
int thrd_sleep( const struct timespec* time_point, struct timespec* remaining )
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_sleep

Comment: That would be great if I *had* a threads.h. Both clang and gcc define `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`, and the only threads.h I have is the linux kernel headers one, which is definitely not the right one.

Answer (score 2):

There in `<windows.h>` a *Sleep* function and in `<unistd.h>` an *usleep* function

Sleep take miliseconds and usleep take microseconds.

Comment: `usleep` takes microseconds ("u" = "µ"). Thanks for adding the sensible answer to this old question.

Comment: That's great for MS Windows. But I wasn't compiling on Windows. The fact that I was grepping through `/usr/include/` probably gives it away.