# How can I make a for loop work slower in C?

Tags: c, nested-loops

I am trying to implement a nested for loop that I want to get inside of a "n" index every second, and every 8 seconds I will get into a "i" index. If something happens right in that second I will update some things. Right now since the `for` loop is too fast it finishes its job before I can do the thing I'm trying to make. What I'm trying to make is for example, if its between 3rd and 4th seconds go to i=0 and n=2, if and if beat happens, update

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
            if (Beat < 1) {
                input[i] = input[i] + pow(2.0, n);
                for (int k = 1; k < 9; k++) {
                    SPI_Write2(k, input[k - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924468/sleep-function-in-c11. But probably better approach would be to wait for an event, which would be exact

Comment: The key is to have multiple processes, or in case of bare metal MCU, emulate it yourself. You'd use on-chip hardware peripheral timers and let those signal whenever a certain time has elapsed. The most proper solution differs a lot between hosted OS, RTOS and bare metal.

Comment: `pow(2.0, n)` stop doing this. Use `1 << n` instead

Comment: I am not trying to shift the number though only tryig to lit up the corresponding index

Comment: it's irrelevant here, `1 << n` is used to set the bit at index n, i.e. 2^n, but it's tens or hundreds of times faster

Answer (score 3):

On Linux `#include <unistd.h>` on windows `#include <Windows.h>`

```
 sleep(1); //sleep for 1 sec
```

However, trying to avoid any kind of race conditions, with some kind of wait is a bad idea in general. So either go with a callback function or using signals. If it is threaded than e.g. wait for the thread to be joined (or detach it).

The provided code is not sufficient. Also the question seems little unclear.

Comment: I've tried this but this means I need to do my updates right at the finish of sleep, what I'm trying to make is for example, if its between 3rd and 4th second go to i=0 and n=2, if and if beat happens, update

Comment: I still do not totally get it what you try to achieve, but I guess you have to redesign your loop then. Did you think about using additional `if` conditions and using `break/continue`?